# Store uploaded images with Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to upload, convert and store an image in Laravel using Image Magick.

Inside `App\Http\Controllers\ArticleController`:

```
$image = $this->storeMainImage($request->file('thumbnail'));
```

The function:

```
private function storeMainImage($file) {
  $folder = 'uploads/images/'; <--- ?????
  $code = uniqid();
  $thumb_code = $folder . 'thumb_' . $code . '.jpg';
  $image_code = $folder . $code . '.jpg';
  if(@is_array(getimagesize($file))){
    exec('convert '.$file.'  -thumbnail 225x225^ -gravity center -extent 225x225  -compress JPEG -quality 70  -background fill white  -layers flatten  -strip  -unsharp 0.5x0.5+0.5+0.008  '.$thumb_code);
    exec('convert '.$file.'  -compress JPEG -quality 70  -background fill white  -layers flatten  -strip  -unsharp 0.5x0.5+0.5+0.008  '.$image_code);
    return $image_code;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

I don't get any errors with this, but I have no idea if it's actually uploading the file and where abouts it's storing it.

Comment: Try to change Your `$folder` to `public_path('uploads/images/')` and then look for images in `public/uploads/images` directory.

Comment: Alternatively, you can store them in your Storage directory and use a route to display them back, if you don't want them to be publicly accessible.

Answer (score 1):

**$request->file()** can return: **\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile** or **array** or **null**

You should check it before processing. Just dump it with **var_dump($file)** or **dd($file)**. Not sure, but it should not be string.

Use **public_path()** for $folder variable, it will help you to prevent any problems in future.

And also check this awesome package for Laravel: http://image.intervention.io/getting_started/introduction

Comment: That package is awesome! Had no idea how to install ImageMagick on Mac OSX, but that uses GD by default so it's all good. Really easy to use too, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To work with Image Magick, first you have to make sure if your server has that module. Else you can install it. [See this to install imagemagick](http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.setup.php)

Else you can use gd by configuring `image.php` file in your config folder. gd is available by default

since `$folder = 'uploads/images/'; <--- ?????` has no starting point specified, the starting point will be where you are when running the script. Therefore to make sure the storing path, you should define your path using `storage_path()` or `public_path()` if you are storing in `storage` or `public` folder respectively. [Check here for more paths available](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/helpers#paths) according to the version you are using. Given link is for Laravel 5.2. You can change the version at the top right corner of the page.

Answer (score 0):

I've made a script which supports uploading multiple images/files within Laravel, which uses the [Image Intervention](http://image.intervention.io/) package. This maybe useful for you and others on SO. I've added some comments and removed unnecessary code to have a better understanding of what is happening.

**HTML markup**

```
<form method="post" action="{{ route('admin.upload.store') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {{!! csrf_field() !!}}
    <input type="file" name="files[]" accept="image/gif, image/jpeg, image/png">
    <button type="submit">Upload image(s)</button>
</form>
```

**UploadController**

*Uses Laravel's built-in RESTful resource controller routes*

```
/**
 * Store a newly created resource in storage.
 * Supports uploading multiple files at once.
 *
 * @param  Request $request
 * @return Response
 */
public function store(Request $request)
{
    // Loop through the files array
    foreach($request->file('files') as $file) {

        // Validate each file, we want images only
        $validator = Validator::make(compact('file'), [
            'files' => 'mimes:jpeg,bmp,gif,png'
        ]);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return redirect()->route('admin.upload.index')->withErrors($validator);
        }

        // Create a new upload model for the file
        $upload = new Upload([
            'name'      => pathinfo($file->getClientOriginalName(), PATHINFO_FILENAME) . '_' . Str::random(2),
            'extension' => strtolower($file->getClientOriginalExtension()),
            'mimetype'  => $file->getMimeType(),
            'size'      => $file->getSize(),
        ]);

        // Create the image
        $file = Image::make($file)->widen(1200, function($constraint) {
            $constraint->upsize(); // Prevent upsizing the image if doesn't exceed the maximum width
        })->encode($upload->extension);

        // Store it within 'storage/app/uploads'
        Storage::disk('uploads')->put($upload->fullName(), $file);

        // Save the upload file details in the database
        $upload->save();
    }

    return redirect()->route('admin.upload.index')->with(['success' => 'Files uploaded']);
}
```